# Different IP addresses by getLocalHost and getByName("localhost")..why so?

Tags: java, inetaddress

Under what circumstances does `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` return a different IP address than `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")`?

On my system, one returns `192.168.0.2` while the other returns `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Please clarify your question: which one is returning what?

Comment: if you type on a browser http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 you will always connect to the machine from where you are doing the connection. It is like an alias to refer to the machine where you are. This is a very convenient trick for development for example. When you ask for your "visible" IP, you are asking to the system, what address another computer should connect to in order to connect to your machine. Note that this may be a private IP (as yours is) and hence only valid to machines in the same network. So, both results are correct, you just need to know what you intend with the IP.

Answer (score 1):

seems, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() is returning your system ip and InetAddress.getByName("localhost") the loopback address.

I doubt the security manager case described by  Parthian for getByName, 
As per InetAddress API specification for getByName():
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29

The method throws: SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkConnect method doesn't allow the operation.

whereas getLocalHost() doesn't throw any such exception but returns loopback address as failsafe.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29

getByName() needs to connect to DNS to resolve hostname.
getByName() in this case is resolving 'localhost' from /etc/hosts(linux) or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc (windows). The hostname ip pair is user configurable in these files.
To check, you can provide any value to localhost, e.g: localhost 127.0.0.2 in hosts file, and getByName will return it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29):

"[`InetAddress.getLocalHost()`] Returns the address of the local host. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.
Note: The resolved address may be cached for a short period of time.

If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is called with the local host name and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, an InetAddress representing the loopback address is returned."

Probably what's happened is you're getting the [loopback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) because your security manager doesn't allow you to connect using the local subnet's `192` address.

`InetAddress.getByName("localhost")` justs asks the operating system to perform a name resolution, [from what I can tell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29), anyway.

Comment: So, both of them are your address, but only one of them you're actually allowed to connect to- I _think_. Naturally, you'll want to check that.